# How to conduct meaningful comparative analysis of two data sets with different total number of values

Tags: dataset, multiple-comparisons

**Situational Summary:**

> We have two data sets that present the amounts paid during individual user-sessions on two separate products. We are trying to digest the data in these sets to provide a comparative analysis of each product's performance based on the average amounts paid per session, per product.

**Problem:**

> The number of values (aka user-sessions) in each set are significantly different. For example, for a particular period of time Product A might have 200 values in the set whilst Product B will have 500 values in the set for the same period.

**Questions:**

> - How statistically relevant is the difference in # of Values between sets, specifically when trying to determine the average pay-per-session per-product?
> - If the answer to the above question is "very relevant", how do we go about producing meaningful observations about how the two products perform comparatively, given the data in these two sets?

`DISCLAIMER: I have almost zero academic background in statistics, but I have enough exposure to HOPEFULLY be able to interpret your answers well enough. In other words: forgive my ignorance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample size of the two populations can be easily taken into account when comparing them. If you are looking to compare some kind of sample average (pay per session etc.) then you can use t-test. Use the formula for unequal sample size and unequal variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances. Do make sure you understand the assumptions and they are met for your analysis.

Comment: There is so much to fundamental statistics that I need to digest just to make sense of this, but from what I can tell so far it seems like this should do the trick. At the very least, you provided me an answer and a starting point which is more than good enough. Thank you very much!